# Hana Sap B1: Execute query using hdbuserstore - * 10: invalid username or password SQLSTATE: 28000

Tags: hana, suse, sapb1

Actually I'm working in Hana DB and Suse Enterprise Server, my objective is use the Scripting and Cronjob to automatize some tasks.

Using `hdbuserstore` located in `/usr/sap/hdbclient` I've created and profile for create a HANA command line secure connection, [check this link](http://www.hanatutorials.com/p/hana-secure-store-using-hdbuserstore.html).

My profile works perfect, I did:

1. Create a user **backup** into HanaDB, using

   ```
   *create user backup password Aa12345678*
   ```
2. Then, I've added BACKUPS PRIVILEGES to it:

   ```
   *grant BACKUP ADMIN to backup*
   ```

Later, I've used `./hdbuserstore` to create a profile to use via command line:

```
./hdbuserstore SET back5prf localhost:30015 backup Aa12345678
```

Then list the profile: ./hdbuserstore LIST

```
DATA FILE       : /root/.hdb/hanab1/SSFS_HDB.DAT
KEY BACK2PRF
  ENV : NDB@hanab1:30015
  USER: backups
KEY BACK3PRF
  ENV : hanab1:30015
  USER: backups
KEY BACK5PRF
  ENV : localhost:30015
  USER: backup
KEY BACKUPSTORE
  ENV : localhost:30015
  USER: backups
```

How you guys can see, the profile is ready. Finally when I tried to use the following command:

```
./hdbsql -U BACK5PRF "SELECT * FROM SCHEMAS"
```

The system returns the following message:

```
* 10: invalid username or password SQLSTATE: 28000
```

- Why I'm getting this error event the user and password are ok?
- There is other way to execute HANA SQL query without enter into the hdbsql console to automate via Scripting?

Answer (score 0):

This error message can have several causes:

- actual wrong user name/password
- user account is locked (you need to unlock it in the user management)
- user account is a restricted user and not allowed to connect via ODBC/JDBC or from anywhere "outside" SAP HANA

I suggest you make sure that the user works in SAP HANA studio and then setup the cron job.

Comment: Thanks a lot Lars, the thing is that I need to use "EXPORT" Sql statement for cron backups via scripting in Linux. Unfortunately Hana Studio not solve this issue at all. FULL INSTANT BACKUP works well, but I need to create several DB Backup in a day. Any idea?

Comment: This is a whole line of different questions. I propose you use this question to fix your authentication problem and open a new one for the backup topic.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the cause was that I used a $ in my password which gets treated as special character in linux (and there more special characters).
So in this case one solution is not to use any character that a treated as special characters or to escape them which in my case resulted the following command for hdbuserstore:

```
hdbuserstore SET BKADMIN 1xx.x.x.xx:30015 ADMIN_BACKUP password\$12
```

Check the thread on [answer.sap.com](https://answers.sap.com/questions/518509/using-credentials-from-hdbuserstore-results-in-err.html?childToView=519816#answer-519816).